# How to perform addition operation using the hash map

Tags: android, hashmap

HASH MAP 
How to perform the addition when an hash map getting an input from the user
through the Edit text in android
final HashMap map = new HashMap<>();

```
    map.put("input1", data1.getText().toString());
    map.put("input2", data2.getText().toString());
    map.put("input3", data3.getText().toString());
```

and i want to store  and view the value in textview

Comment: Do you think your title and your content has any relation?

Comment: sorry the content heading was wrong i want to do the addition operation using the hash map any one pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I Didn't Get What you want

You have to convert that into Integers using`Integer.parseInt(data(x).getText.toString())`

You can use HashMap.get() method

Do it with your own logic

I Guess It is Like this:

```
Integer Sum = ((map.get("input1")) + (map.get("input2")) + (map.get("input3")))
```